# No response after initial phone interview

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I had a phone interview with a startup company last week, I was speaking to the CTO. Towards the end of the interview he said next stage is a face to face interview and he will email me the details of it. The day of the interview comes and I still have not received any email regarding a location. I sent an email and no response. Any advice on how should I proceed?

Comment: And advice is to move on with another application.

Comment: Yes.  No follow-up means you've not been successful.  It's a bit of a shame that interviewers like to imply there's a further step and then not go ahead with their words.  It's usually because it's easier to say nothing than explain why they're retracting something they said in the interview.

Comment: Check your spam folder.  It's not likely, but it happens.

Comment: It's a bit of a downer but reality is a lot of folks rather not be placed in a spot where there might be potential confrontations. So they rather just say something uplifting, leave on a good note, and then simply ignore any future interactions to avoid explaining anything. It's a sad reality of job hunting but once you reach the "ignore" stages, then it is your cue to move on to other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a few of the comments have said, it's probably just best to move on. No contact before or on the day of a supposed interview is not a great sign. Most likely, as it is, the company did not want to proceed further with your interview process. Don't take that in a bad way, either; it happens, and it's a normal part of the job process.

Besides those points, if the company is that flaky about proper communication, it doesn't sound like the kind of place you would want to work anyway.

Comment: To be honest I didn't expect too much as the company was very new they only came into existence a few months ago, having worked in a startup environment before I have an idea of how hectic it can be at times. As you said if they can't communicate properly not a good indication of a ideal work environment.

Comment: Exactly. You don't want to work for a boss who tells you Yes because he doesn't want to tell you No.